# React.js: Parent state values not passing into child properties + Fetch API data cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am encountering several issues in a very basic color harmony picker I am developing. I am still a beginner in React and JSX. I initially had it put up on GitHub so the full files are on there, but I moved it over to Codepen instead.

[Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dantou/pen/OOKgdZ)

I made a lot of comments so sorry if they're a bit much, but hopefully they help. My problems don't begin until line 41, the displayHarmonies() method of the DataStore class. The values passed to it come from my App (parent) component:

```
displayHarmonies(color, harmony) {
    //color and harmony pass in dynamically just fine...this.data will not return anything, not even "undefined"
    console.log(color + " is the color and " + harmony + " is the harmony...and dataStore.displayHarmonies says: " + this.data);

    this.registeredWatchers.map((watcher) => {
        let result = "not green"; //result and resultHex will be determined with an underscore statement that will associate the color & harmony choice (primary + foreign key concept) and will return correct harmony color(s)
        let resultHex = "#HEX";

        appState.harmonyColor = result;
        appState.harmonyHex = resultHex;

        //call to app component's onDataChange() method, where new states will be set using the the appState data we just set in lines 49 and 50
        watcher.onDataChange();
    })
}
```

As you can see from my first comment, the only part that doesn't log to the console is this.data, which is set in the constructor for the DataStore:

```
constructor(data) {
    //store that data in the object
    //data is not being received from object instance of dataStore on line 187
    this.data = data;
```

On line 187 I make an instance of the DataStore and pass it a variable named `data`. Prior to being used, this variable is  initialized and then assigned to parsed JSON data via Fetch API:

```
let data = [];

//use polyfill for older browsers to do Ajax request
fetch("data/data.json").then((response) => {
//if we actually got something
    if (response.ok) {
        //then return the text we loaded
        return response.text();
    }
}).then((textResponse) => {
    data = JSON.parse(textResponse);
});
```

If I console out the data in the second fetch `.then()` method, the JSON comes back just fine. As soon as I try to use the `data` variable anywhere else in the application, it returns nothing, as shown in the `displayHarmonies()` method's `console.log()`. So that's my first issue, but before I wanted to get to that, I wanted to solve the other issue I was having.

After the `appState` object (initialized prior to the DataStore, under the fetch statement) values get set to the `result` variables, `displayHarmonies()` runs `watcher.onDataChange()` (in the App component/parent) where the `harmonyColor` and `harmonyHex` states get assigned to the new `appState` values:

```
onDataChange() {
    console.log("onDataChange() in App called");
    this.setState({
        harmonyColor: appState.harmonyColor,
        harmonyHex: appState.harmonyHex
    })
}
```

If I log these states out to the console, they are the right values, so that's not the problem. I then pass my states to the `Display` child component to be used as properties:

```
<Display colorChoice={this.state.currentColor} harmonyChoice={this.state.currentHarmony} harmonyColor={this.state.harmonyColor} harmonyHex={this.state.harmonyHex} />
```

I then set the `Display` component states in the constructor, assigning them to the props that are being sent to it with each new rendition of the application. I then display the data onto the DOM with the `Display` component's render method. What's odd is that the application will display the initial states (color: red, harmony: direct, harmonyColor: green, etc.) just fine, but as soon as a change is made, the data on the DOM does not update. The initial data is loaded in the same way though: by passing the parent's states into the child's properties. I have a few `console.log()`s in place that seem to prove why this should work, however, it does not. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, and hope this is not too much for one question!

Comment: Why do you use the `onDataChange` do you wish to circumvent normal state management? Did you choose any form of state management? eg: redux, or just internal component state? Instance properties containing data are rather a no go in react

Comment: The way the data flows through my application, `onDataChange` is getting called any time one of my `<li>` elements in my Picker component is clicked on. It then sets new state values for `harmonyColor` and `harmonyHex`. I want these states to move back into my `<Display />` component as a property like it did in the initial app state.

Comment: [Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dantou/pen/OOKgdZ)

Comment: After checking the codepen, I think you are trying to create your own state management in a way you have probably done before with other frameworks. There is no need for that, and that is probably what is complicating things a bit in your app. Also note that you are reassigning `data` with the `responseText`, therefor your `DataStore` will never have the response

Comment: I figured this was just the natural method of state management in react. I use nearly an identical method in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dantou/pen/qVVBzd), except this one works just fine, however my data is a JS object literal. Also, yes `data` is being reassigned to the parsed version of `responseText`, however data still remains in a higher scope, so why can't I pass it to the `DataStore` instance?

Comment: Okay! I solved my first problem of state management. I needed to call to `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in my `Display` component, so this rerenders the `Display` states whenever the parent `App` component sets new state values and passes them to Display as props. This allows the data to update fluently for Display. All I do is use `nextProps.prop` instead of `this.props.prop` when setting the state in `componentWillReceiveProps`. I still need to solve the issue I am getting when attempting to receive and use my JSON data, however.

Comment: I think you might have some misconceptions on how React works exactly, there should never be a reason for you to call that method, it is part of the react life cycle. As for the `data` variable, once you add it to the dataStore it's reference is saved inside the `data` property of the dataStore, however, if you reassign data afterwards, the new data will just be a new reference, and the data inside dataStore will not be affected, that will still have the old data. Theoretically, we could start a chat, if you want to clear up more things, I will check if I can create an easier example for you

Comment: As I am a beginner with React it's very possible I might have misconceptions on how it works exactly. I know the general purpose of it, how it uses props and states, etc...I have also worked with Facebook's flux architecture as well so layers of abstraction aren't necessarily the issue for me. If not forcing it to rerender with `compononentWillReceiveProps`, how can I get the child component to rerender once it receives new prop data from the parent? Also, I see what you're saying with `data`, messing around with the console shows me that fetch runs after everything else. A chat might help!

Comment: @Icepickle feel free to fork the codepen, even though the fetch statement isn't calling to any JSON files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160861/discussion-between-icepickle-and-lefty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a bit to your current code, at the end of the post, I have added an alternative solution, so if this is tl;dr; just skip to the snippet at the end :)

A first remark would be on the `data` variable that you wish to pass on to your `DataStore`, nl (I left out some parts, as they are irrelevant to the discussion)

```
let data = [];

fetch("data/data.json").then(( response ) => {
    data = JSON.parse( response.text() );
});
//... later down the code
var store = new DataStore(data);
```

Here you are reassigning the `data` variable inside the `then` promise chain of your fetch call. Although the assignment will appear to work, the data that now is on `store.data` will be an empty array, and the global variable will `data` will now contain the parsed `response.text()`. You should probably just push in the data you have just parsed (but in my example, I didn't even include the `DataStore` so this is just for future reference)

In your CodePen, you seem to mixing props & state for your `Display` component. That is in essence a no-op, you shouldn't mix them unless you really know what you are doing. Also note, that by calling `this.setState` inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle method, the app will automatically re-render more than needed. I am referring to this code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    color: nextProps.colorChoice,
    harmony: nextProps.harmonyChoice,
    harmonyColor: nextProps.harmonyColor,
    harmonyHex: nextProps.harmonyHex
  });
}
```

But you are then rendering like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* these aren't changing even though states are being set */}
      <p><b>Color:</b> {this.state.color}</p>
      <p><b>Harmony:</b> {this.state.harmony}</p>
      <p><b>Harmony Color(s):</b> {this.state.harmonyColor} ({this.state.harmonyHex})</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here you should remove the `componentWillReceiveProps` method, and render values from `this.props` as you are passing these along from your `App`.

**Alternative solution**

As mentioned in the comments, your code currently is doing a lot more than it should do to pass state between parent and child components.

One thing you should keep in mind, is that when a component state gets changed, react will re-render the component automatically. When it sees that the virtual DOM has discrepancies with the real DOM it will automatically replace those components.

In that sense, your `DataStore` is not necessary. Depending on how you want to manage state, the component will react on those changes.

Since your app uses Component State (which is fine for small applications, once you want to move to bigger applications, you will probably want to move on to something like Redux, or MobX), the only thing you need to do, is to make sure that you set the correct components state to trigger the rendering.

As an example, I remade your code in a cleaner way:

```js
const Choice = ({ header, values, onChange, activeValue }) => {
  return <ul>
    <li><h1>{ header }</h1></li>
    { values.map( (value, key) => <li 
      key={key+value}
      className={classNames( { active: value === activeValue, item: true } )} 
      onClick={() => onChange( value )}>{ value }</li> ) }
  </ul>
};

const colors = ['red', 'green', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow'];
const harmonies = ['direct', 'split', 'analogous'];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      activeColor: undefined,
      activeHarmony: undefined
    };
  }
  onColorChanged( color ) {
    this.setState({ activeColor: color });
  }
  onHarmonyChanged( harmony ) {
    this.setState({ activeHarmony: harmony });
  }
  render() {
    let { activeColor, activeHarmony } = this.state;
    return <div>
      <Choice 
        header="Choose color" 
        values={colors} 
        activeValue={activeColor} 
        onChange={(...args) => this.onColorChanged(...args)} />
      <Choice 
        header="Choose harmony" 
        values={harmonies} 
        activeValue={activeHarmony}
        onChange={(...args) => this.onHarmonyChanged(...args)} />
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

```css
h1 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
.active { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.0/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Now, there are some things in this sample code that might need some explanation. For one, this code has 2 component types, 1 presentational component called `Choice` which is stateless, and one container component called `App` which delegates it's state to it's children.

A bit more information about container & presentational components can be found on the [blog](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) of Dan Abramov (redux creator)

The essence of the above concept is just this, the `App` component is responsible for the state, and for sharing it with it's children. So, all state changes need to be made on the `App` component. As you can see in the render, the `App` simply passes its state along:

```
render() {
  let { activeColor, activeHarmony } = this.state;
  return <div>
    <Choice 
      header="Choose color" 
      values={colors} 
      activeValue={activeColor} 
      onChange={(...args) => this.onColorChanged(...args)} />
    <Choice 
      header="Choose harmony" 
      values={harmonies} 
      activeValue={activeHarmony}
      onChange={(...args) => this.onHarmonyChanged(...args)} />
  </div>;
}
```

The `App` passes a change handler along to the `Choice` component that can be called when a selection should occur, this gets forwarded to the `App`, the state changes, and app re-renders, allowing the `Choice` component to update it's elements.

```
const Choice = ({ header, values, onChange, activeValue })
```

Based on the props passed into it, the `Choice` component can decide which is the active item at the moment of rendering. As you can see, the props are destructed. `header`, `values`, `onChange` and `activeValue` are all properties on the `props` of the component, but to save time, we can assign these values at ones to a variable and use them in the rendering.

Comment: Thank you @Icepickle for the excellent answer. Not only did you help me understand what I was doing wrong with my original solution, but you also gave me the alternative solution that really simplifies the App processes. I never knew you could use presentational components by using a `const` the way you did.

Answer (score 2):

I tried cloning your repo, but it seems to be nested in another repo. With your current setup, this may work:

In your App component, you can put this lifecycle method to fetch the data, and then set the state with the received data.:

```
    componentDidMount(){
      fetch("data/data.json").then((response) => {
    //if we actually got something
    if (response.ok) {
        //then return the text we loaded
        return response.text();
    }
}).then((textResponse) => {
  this.setState({
    data : JSON.parse(textResponse);
  })

});
    }
```

In the return statement, you can render the data store as a child so App can pass the data like this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataStore data={this.state.data} />
      <h1>Color Harmonies</h1>
        {/* assigns this.colorChosen() & this.harmonyChosen() methods as properties to be called in Picker component */}
        <Picker colorChosen={this.colorChosen.bind(this)} harmonyChosen={this.harmonyChosen.bind(this)}/>
        {/* give Display component props that are dynamically set with states */}
        <Display colorChoice={this.state.currentColor} harmonyChoice={this.state.currentHarmony} harmonyColor={this.state.harmonyColor} harmonyHex={this.state.harmonyHex} />
    </div>
);
```

Then, your data store should receive the data as a prop, so you can use it like this:

```
displayHarmonies(color, harmony) {
    //color and harmony pass in dynamically just fine...this.data will not return anything, not even "undefined"
    console.log(color + " is the color and " + harmony + " is the harmony...and dataStore.displayHarmonies says: " + this.props.data); //data is received in the properties so you can use it. 
//other code


})
```

Doing this, you should also be able to remove this.data from the constructor of the DataStore component.

Also in Data store, youll want to to allow it to accept props like this:

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that `DataStore` point to `this.state.data` seeing you are now setting the state?

Comment: The app component sets the data from fetch so the data store is receiving the data as a prop from the app component.

Comment: Yeah, I am pointing to `<DataStore data={this.data} />` which probably should be `<DataStore data={this.state.data} />`

Comment: Ohh my mistake. Sorry looking at this on a phone at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry about the nested repo mishap. However, I tried what you suggested and I can't seem to get it to like using properties `this.props.data` inside of DataStore even though I changed the constructor and extended the class name to ensure it was a child component of App. It tells me I can't declare data of undefined (presumably `this.props`). [I added a CodePen hoping it would be more useful.](https://codepen.io/Dantou/pen/OOKgdZ)

Comment: In the data store component youll want constructor(props){super(props)} so it can receive props}. Sorry still on a phone.

Comment: Yeah, in my previous comment I mentioned changing the constructor to ensure it was a react component, what I was referring to was `constructor(props){super(props)}`. I also made it so `class DataStore extends Component (or React.Component in Codepen)`. Oddly enough, it still doesn't like the call to `this.props.data`. Do I have to get rid of the instance of the `DataStore` object at the bottom of my code? Because I use that for more than just passing the `data` variable to the DataStore.